# Regenerate WordPress thumbnails with media hosted on S3

Tags: wordpress, amazon-s3, wordpress-theming

I have a WordPress site that uses the WPRO (WordPress Read Only) plugin to host all media files on Amazon S3. I've changed the thumbnail and image sizes in my custom theme, and uploading new images to the media library uses the new sizes. However, when I try to regenerate all thumbnails using "Regenerate Thumbnails," it doesn't work, often complaining that the original cannot be found.

How can I force the regenerate thumbnails plugin to use the original image on S3 to recreate the thumbnails for existing images?

Comment: Did you try to contact the authors of the regenerate thumbnails plugin?

Comment: Have you attempted to clear the s3 amazon cache before running the thumbnail regenerate?

Comment: "often complaining that the original cannot be found" - Are you sure the originals were uploaded to S3? Perhaps there is a configuration on the plugin to get rid of the originals in order to save space.

Comment: Can you just use the largest available size to regenerate?

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin that claim it can "Force Regenerate Thumbnail" i remember using a year ago and it worked for my case at the time.

> https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/force-regenerate-thumbnails/

But has of today i personally never go that route anymore for efficiency reasons since a theme can change a lot and edge cases can appear depending on client/corporate needs. To circumvent any "Regeneration" you could install.

> https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/fly-dynamic-image-resizer/

The gist of the plugin would be that you define your sizes but are only generated when someone is calling a specific image, thus allowing you to change theme image sizes at any time without going through a Regeneration Process (which can be very long). Any generated file sizes can be deleted also at any time as long as the original exists.